# Select min of time that got group by status and need more than 1 values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find min time of shift worker but some days worker have 2 shifts.

Table t:

```
|     ID   |   date     |  time    |  status  |
| -------- | ---------- | -------- | -------- |           
|     1    | 2022-01-01 | 08:00:00 | Shift In | 
|     1    | 2022-01-01 | 08:15:00 | Shift In |
|     1    | 2022-01-01 | 10:30:00 | Shift Out|
|     1    | 2022-01-01 | 12:15:00 | Shift In |
|     1    | 2022-01-01 | 12:18:00 | Shift In |
|     1    | 2022-01-01 | 14:52:00 | Shift Out|
|     1    | 2022-01-01 | 15:00:00 | Shift Out|
|     2    | 2022-01-01 | 17:15:00 | Shift In |
|     2    | 2022-01-01 | 18:15:00 | Shift Out|
|     2    | 2022-01-01 | 18:18:00 | Shift Out|
```

Output I need:

```
|     ID   |   date     |  time    |  status  |
| -------- | ---------- | -------- | -------- |           
|     1    | 2022-01-01 | 08:00:00 | Shift In | 
|     1    | 2022-01-01 | 10:30:00 | Shift Out|
|     1    | 2022-01-01 | 12:15:00 | Shift In |
|     1    | 2022-01-01 | 14:52:00 | Shift Out|
|     2    | 2022-01-01 | 17:15:00 | Shift In |
|     2    | 2022-01-01 | 18:15:00 | Shift Out|
```

I need min of time for each shift. When I try output always shows 1 of each employee so I have no idea.

I try to find solutions for return output of min time of shift worker that work more than 1 time in a day on SQL or PL/SQL but I still no idea.

Comment: Are you sure you described the reuqirements correctly? If more than two rows having the same status appear before it changes again, should then also be selected one row only?

Comment: You are mentioning two different DBMS here. Which are you using? **SQL Server** is a database system by Microsoft. PL/SQL on the other hand is a programming language built into the **Oracle** database system.

Comment: Yes! my boss need output like this, I edit my mentioning right now Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just want to list all Shift In and Shift Out rows, but there are some redundant rows, such as Shift In at 8:30 when there is already a row for Shift In at 8:00. You want to remove the redundant rows and only keep the first row of such recurring statuses.

Use `LAG` to see the status of the previous row.

```
select id, date, time, status
from
(
  select
    t.*,
    lag(status) over (partition by id order by date, time) as prev_status
  from mytable t
)
where prev_status is null or prev_status <> status
order by id, date, time;
```